# Comatiblity of application deployed on 10g with 11g weblogic

Tags: weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

My development environment was configured on 10g weblogic. Due to business need change we need to migrate to 11g. Will applications working on 10g continue to be compatible on 11g weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading from 10.0/10.3.0(10g) to 10.3.6(11g), your application should work .Recompile code on new jdk 1.6 and deploy on 11g.